# Diff with 2 files

Tags: diff

Try'd a lot of different commands, Diff / comm  / grep / etc...
But dont know how to manage this. It's for my bash script.

I want to get the result of the correct / incorrect answers. 
the example below should be 2 correct / 3 in-correct.

I have 2 files:
1: Correct-answers with this inside:

```
Answer A
Answer B
Answer C
Answer D
Answer A
```

2: Fill in with this inside:

```
Answer A
Answer R
Answer B
Answer D
Answer C
```

Answer (score 2):

This is paste and gawk (you mentioned etc).

```
paste file1 file2 -d ',' | gawk 'BEGIN { FS="," } $1==$2{print "correct"} $1!=$2{print "incorrect"}'
```

`paste` just put the two together side by side

`-d` is for delimiter similarly `FS` means field separator. They have to be the same and some character that you don't have in your file (so not space which is default)

`BEGIN` means we're setting `FS` that just one time before we start.

It's output will be:

```
correct
incorrect
incorrect
correct
incorrect
```

Comment: Thnx for your answer!!! And sorry for offtopic.